# How to get Item being added before commit in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I've got a ViewModel, which is used by a View with a DataGrid.
In the DataGrid I try to allow the User directly to add new rows, but some of the columns need to open a new Dialog for the value. 
Therefor I set the SelectedItem - Binding and added some Extensions to allow binding OnBeginningEdit and OnRowEditEnding to custom commands in my ViewModel.
Now I have the problem, that I want to get the current "new" item, which is partly filled by the GUI, before calling CommitEdit on the DataGrid. 
I tried to use IEditableCollectionView and use CurrentAddItem of it, to achieve this.
But the CurrentAddItem does not get filled with the items entered in the GUI.

How may I achieve that properly in MVVM?

```cs
public ICommand DataGridDoubleClickCommand
{  
    get
    {    
        return new Command(
        delegate (object obj)
        {
            var dataGrid = ((object[])obj)[0] as DataGrid;
            var args = ((object[])obj)[1] as MouseButtonEventArgs;

            if (dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex != 2)
            {
                return;
            }

            args.Handled = true;

            ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.Items);

            IEditableCollectionView iecv = (IEditableCollectionView)view;

            if(iecv.IsAddingNew)
            {
             // tried to use iecv.CurrentAddItem here - but was empty
            }

            dataGrid.CommitEdit();

...
```

Comment: BTW `((object[])obj)[0]` is unsafe, sloppy, and hard to maintain. Consider refactoring such things.

Comment: I know, but that was not the question.